# Binomial regression model for low number of events?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, binomial-distribution

Say I have a binomial model with response variable $Y = (Y_i)_{1 \le i \le M}$ which corresponds to the vector of number of successes for $D = (D_i)_{1 \le i \le M}$ the vector of number of events, covariates $X = (X_{i,j})_{1 \le i \le M, 1 \le j \le T}$, link function $g$,  $g(X \beta) = E[Y]$. Here we have $M \gg T$ and M isn't "small". I was wondering if there were any known modifications to add to the model to take better care of the case where the $D_i$ are small? Does it ring any bell?

Thank you all.

Comment: Why standard binomial would not suffice?

Comment: Maybe it would, to be frank, I just had the hunch that with small $D_i$ the estimation of $\beta$ would be worse because it would give less information about the expectation of $Y$. So as there sometimes exists corrections for small sample regressions there might be something similar but for "small" number of events.

Comment: With low events, things like separation become more prominent, so it can be helpful to keep that in mind (and check things like the conditioning of the design matrices of the zeros and that of the ones separately). But this model as it stands is appropriate for this kind of data, as @Tim says. (though may benefit from regularization if there is separation).

Comment: One possibility is regularization ...